# JAX-RS @consume("text/plain") does not get the String

Tags: java, rest, post, jax-rs, postman

I have method like,

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes("text/plain")
public File addFile(String filePath){
    return fileService.addFile(filePath);
}
```

And I am using "Postman rest client" for testing the post request and simply type a path like **c:\myFile.txt** in the raw section

but no String is passed to method, but when I hard-code the path it works

Is the problem from @consume ?

Comment: Have you selected 'text/plain' from the postman dropdown?

Comment: @yogidilip , now I did but no difference

Comment: Do you need to add @RequestBody to your parameter? For example, `public File addFile(@RequestBody String filePath){` (I might be thinking of spring MVC here...)

Comment: @BretC there is no such annotation only '@RequestWrapper' which is not allowed

Comment: @AmirHM - sorry, I was thinking of Spring MVC...

Comment: Adding @RequestBody final String sampleMessage helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the answer below

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public File addFile(String filePath){
    return fileService.addFile(filePath);
}
```

And the header content type 
as **text/plain** while sending the request to server from postman

for your reference please see the image below
[image]

Comment: Thank you , it worked the problem was with content type which was not registered in presets

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, there is no annotation to fetch the body of the request with Jax-RS ; The original definition of the service is correct.
The problem probably comes from postman settings. 
You should select Body > raw > Text (text/plain).